# OpenLDAP ppolicy working with passwd, but not ldappasswd

Tags: ldap, openldap, pam

I've been working on this for about a week, and can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I've got `passwd` working, letting users change their own ldap password from a client machine, and it working with the ppolicy overlay:

```
$ passwd
Current Password: 
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is the same as the old one
passwd: Have exhausted maximum number of retries for service
passwd: password unchanged
```

However, when I use `ldappasswd` to change my password, it allows me to create one letter passwords, and palindromes, but **not** passwords in my history:

```
$ ldappasswd -H ldap://**** -x -D "uid=test,ou=Users,dc=***,dc=***,dc=***" -W -A -S
Old password: 
Re-enter old password: 
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Enter LDAP Password: 
$
# no issues entering "a" as the password (this is bad)
```

```
$ ldappasswd -H ldap://**** -x -D "uid=test,ou=Users,dc=***,dc=***,dc=***" -W -A -S
Old password: 
Re-enter old password: 
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Enter LDAP Password: 
Result: Constraint violation (19)
Additional info: Password is in history of old passwords
$
# entered "password" as the password and it doesn't let me change it
```

Ideally, I'd like both `passwd` and `ldappasswd` to follow the password policy.

Here are my access rules in the slapd config:

`/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif`

```
...
# manager is the root bind dn, with password in /etc/ldap.secret
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn.base="uid=manager,ou=Users,dc=***,dc=***,dc=***" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * by * read by dn.base="uid=manager,ou=Users,dc=***,dc=***,dc=***" write
...
```

It seems to me like `passwd` is binding to the root dn, because removing the access for the manager account makes `passwd` stop working entirely, and `ldappasswd` is unaffected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages from `passwd` **do not look like they come from the ppolicy overlay at all**. They come from *local* checks done by other PAM modules, most likely `pam_cracklib`. Naturally, local PAM configuration will have no effect on tools that directly contact the LDAP server.

In other words, that sounds like your local tools are working fine, but the ppolicy overlay *is not* working right (i.e. it's not correctly enforcing the min-length limit; your local config was enforcing that instead).

(And on a different note, if your PAM LDAP configuration is set up to bind using the "manager" DN... that's kind of *bad.* It means anyone who gets root – or even just a "file read" exploit – on any server can immediately get the manager password from /etc/ldap.conf and obtain full access to your LDAP directory.)

Comment: You're right, the pam configurations are all over the place and I did have cracklib installed, I'm moving away from using the passwd command and just having users change their password with ldappasswd, thank you for the help though.